# Creating a reference to a custom class locally using alloc-init (tried with new as well just to be sure) keyword doesn't get deallocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

Here is how I create the object reference:

```
-(void)someMethod
{
    CustomClass *customObject=[[CustomClass alloc] init];
}
```

As far as I know, customObject should be deallocated right after the scope of this method ends. Although, what I see in the Leaks instrument is that this appears to be a leak. It is not getting deallocated.

For your reference, here is the call tree of the allocation of the object:

[image]

When I create this object as a strong property and then initialize it as:

```
_customObject=[[CustomClass alloc] init];
```

It doesn't show up as a leak. That means it does get deallocated.

Why doesn't this object get deallocated via ARC when I create it not as a property in the method?

**EDIT**

At the time I posted this question I was testing on the iPhone 6 (8.4) simulator. I tested the app on an actual device just now and I cannot find this leak.

I don't understand this uneven behavior.

Comment: At what point are you checking if `customObject` is being deallocated?

Comment: @rmaddy the someMethod method is in a view controller. The leak appears when this view controller is popped from the navigation stack. I do not check where it is being deallocated, I see that in the leaks. Please also see the edit to the question I just made.

Comment: When it comes to leaks, never trust the simulator. The memory model in the simulator is different than on real devices. Remember, it's a simulator, not an emulator. If you don't have a leak on the device then that's good.

Comment: @rmaddy lesson learnt. Thanks! Was trying to find out the reason since a couple of hours.